# CKEditor webpack loader issues

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to use CKEditor in a AdminLTE project.
This project has a url loader in the rules:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@ckeditor"),
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
```

this loads all the fontawesome glyphs.

When I want to add the CKEditor svg rule:

```
{
            // Or /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/ if you want to limit this loader
            // to CKEditor 5's icons only.
            test: /\.svg$/,

            use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
        },
```

all hell breaks loose and the loaders give parse error about unexpected tokens on all found svgs.
When I remove the svg option in the above rule's test regex, no fontawesome svg is shown, but the CKEditor's svg get through.

I searched high and low, but I can't seem to figure out how to merge the two rules, or how to separate them enough so both apply.

A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like you'r headed down the right path - use an `include` for the ckeditor regex test, and an `exclude` for the non-ckeditor regex test.